# how to send data to server with select tag without form

Tags: html, django, jquery

I have a select tag in my html file. i want when user change his/her selection, my page which have to work with ajax, sends the value of user selection to my views.py function and then i recreate the page with this value.
my html code:

```
<div id="response>
    <select name="page_length_name" id="page_length_id">
        <option id="opt1">10</option>
        <option id="opt2">20</option>
        <option id="opt3">30</option>
        <option id="opt4">40</option>
    </select>
     //here is a table
</div>
```

(this select tag isn't in form). i want it to be fixed untill user change data. so i think i have to use cookie. i don't know can i use function like this, although select isn't in form? Should it be "POST" method? can post only be used in forms? if yes, so how can i send data(my select tag) to server?

```
$(function() {
                $('#page_length_id').change(function() {
                temp = ["page_length_id"].options[selectedIndex].value;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: temp,
                    url: 'backup/',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("success");
                        $("#response").html(data);
                    }
                });
            })
```

and also how can i force this select value to be in cookie? is it enough to do it by only this line of code in views.py?:

```
table_length = request.COOKIES.get('table_length')
```

here is my viwes.py:

```
def backup(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            table_length = request.COOKIES.get('table_length')
        except Exception:
            table_length = 10
        if not page_length:
            table_length = 10 
        //here i create the page with xsl and send it to a page to be shown 
        result = style.applyStylesheet(doc)
        out = style.saveResultToString( result )
        ok =  mark_safe(out)
        style.freeStylesheet()
        doc.freeDoc()
        result.freeDoc()
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            return HttpResponse(ok)
        else:
            return render_to_response("show.html", {
                'str': ok,
                }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

thank you.

Comment: Too many question. Please, specify a problem you have. Does your approach raise errors? Also, did you set your ajax-request correctly with csrf: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: first of all: i want to know how can i send user selection to the server? (i don't have form, so i want to know can i use "$.ajax({type: "POST"..."? can i use post method while i don't have any forms?)

Comment: nothing happens when user change the options in select tag. hmmm... in my other view function which works with ajax, i don't have csrf and it works.

Answer (score 3):

for the ajax problem, you can easily use the

```
  $.ajax({
    type:"POT",
    url :....,
    data:{
        .......
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("{% csrf_token %}").find("input").attr("value"),
    },    
    dataType:"html",
    error:function(data){},
    success:function(data){
      ....
    },
  });
```

but you need to put

```
<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" value="{{csrf_token}}"/>
```

in your html

if you send data with form you should use csrf too

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: really thanks. when i want to send a form data (with post method), should i use csrf too?

Comment: yes you should use csrf too

<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/